# Find the lyapunov function to prove the asymptotic stability

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let's the following non linear system:
$\begin{cases}
\dot{x_1}=x_2&\\
\dot{x_2}=-x_1^3&\\
\end{cases}$
determine if the origin is asymptotically stable and in this case if it is globally asymptotically stable.
I have tried to linearized the system but I have obtained two eigenvalues equal to $0$. I have tried to find out an opportune $V$ to prove that the origin is AS but I can't. 
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no asymptotic stability. Taken the system

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = -x_1^3
}
$$

and multiplying by $x_1^3, x_2$ as

$$
\cases{
x_1^3\dot x_1 = x_1^3x_2\\
x_2\dot x_2 = -x_1^3x_2
}
$$

and adding we have

$$
\frac 12x_1^4+x_2^2 = C
$$

so those orbits characterize a center around the origin.

[image]

Comment: So when I can't to find out a certain $V$ s.t the derivative is negative definite ,can I try to prove that around the origin the orbits of the non linear system are closed?

Comment: You can try to obtain a movement integral like the one found.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try something with $x_1^4$ instead of $x_1^2$.

Comment: Nothing changes... $\dot{V}=x_1^3(x_2)+x_2(-x_1^3)=0$

Comment: So you found a constant of motion, that's good news! But how did you get $\dot V=0$ with your original $V$, by the way? That must have been some mistake in the calculation.